# How to solve rack app error in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

So I'm working on a project right now and I have implemented webpack through webpacker gem in rails 5.

Everything seems to be working fine until I get this error in my log file :

```
    2018-02-14 19:46:13 -0800: Rack app error handling request { GET /packs/application-a4b639671cab02ef63f8.js }
#<Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout>
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/protocol.rb:181:in `rbuf_fill'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/protocol.rb:157:in `readuntil'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/protocol.rb:167:in `readline'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http/response.rb:40:in `read_status_line'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http/response.rb:29:in `read_new'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-proxy-0.6.3/lib/net_http_hacked.rb:53:in `begin_request_hacked'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-proxy-0.6.3/lib/rack/http_streaming_response.rb:60:in `response'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-proxy-0.6.3/lib/rack/http_streaming_response.rb:29:in `headers'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-proxy-0.6.3/lib/rack/proxy.rb:120:in `perform_request'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/webpacker-3.2.0/lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:16:in `perform_request'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-proxy-0.6.3/lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/server.rb:624:in `handle_request'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/server.rb:438:in `process_client'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/server.rb:302:in `block in run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

I believe this has something to do with webpack in `public/packs/` but I do not know what might trigger the error and how to fix it.

I would love some help from more experienced developers.

Thank you

Comment: Can u add `application.js` file? if using ./tree, best list file names...

Comment: @7urkm3n I solved the problem by stopping the server , launching bin/webpack-dev-server and rails s

Answer (score 0):

Comment out it in your environment file.

```
# config.assets.quiet = true
```